# jQuery AJAX 200 Undefined error with multiple / same name attributes[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I am submitting some data which some have the same name="" values like name="product_name[]" etc... which is why i think my current ajax is failing but not sure and not sure how to resolve. Anyone have any ideas? i.e

```
customer_name:James
customer_address_1:21 Test Road
customer_town:Test town
customer_postcode required:cm16 4rr
customer_email:james@email.com
customer_address_2:other part
customer_county:something
customer_phone:48486486486
customer_name_ship:James
customer_name_2_ship:other part
customer_town_ship:Test town
customer_address_1:21 Test Road
customer_county_ship:something
customer_postcode_ship:cm16 4rr
invoice_product[]:Versa Table - Wildberry
invoice_product_qty[]:2
invoice_product_price[]:200
invoice_product_discount[]:20%
invoice_product[]:Versa Table - Wildberry
invoice_product_qty[]:4
invoice_product_price[]:149
invoice_product_discount[]:
invoice_product[]:Versa Table - Wildberry
invoice_product_qty[]:1
invoice_product_price[]:120
invoice_product_discount[]:40
invoice_subtotal:996.00
invoice_discount:120.00
invoice_shipping:40.00
invoice_vat:199.20
invoice_total:996.00
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/90jqq4ym/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // add product
    $("#action_add_product").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        actionAddProduct();
    });

    // create invoice
    $("#action_create_invoice").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        actionCreateInvoice();
    });

    // enable date pickers for due date and invoice date
    var dateFormat = $(this).attr('data-vat-rate');
    $('#invoice_date, #invoice_due_date').datetimepicker({
        showClose: false,
        format: dateFormat
    });

    // copy customer details to shipping
    $('input.copy-input').on("change keyup paste", function () {
        $('input#' + this.id + "_ship").val($(this).val());
    });

    // remove product row
    $('#invoice_table').on('click', ".delete-row", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        calculateTotal();
    });

    // add new product row on invoice
    var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
    $(".add-row").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table'); 
    });

    calculateTotal();

    $('#invoice_table, #invoice_totals').on('change keyup paste', '.calculate', function() {
        updateTotals(this);
        calculateTotal();
    });

    function updateTotals(elem) {

        var tr = $(elem).closest('tr'),
            quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', tr).val(),
            price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', tr).val(),
            isPercent = $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val().indexOf('%') > -1,
            percent = $.trim($('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val().replace('%', '')),
            subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        if(percent && $.isNumeric(percent) && percent !== 0) {
            if(isPercent){
                subtotal = subtotal - ((parseFloat(percent) / 100) * subtotal);
            } else {
                subtotal = subtotal - parseFloat(percent);
            }
        } else {
            $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val('');
        }

        $('.calculate-sub', tr).val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    }

    function calculateTotal(){

        var grandTotal = 0,
            disc = 0;

        $('#invoice_table tbody tr').each(function() {
            var c_sbt = $('.calculate-sub', this).val(),
                quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', this).val(),
                price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', this).val() || 0,
                subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

            grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
            disc += subtotal - parseFloat(c_sbt);
        });

        // VAT, DISCOUNT, SHIPPING, TOTAL, SUBTOTAL:
        var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal),
            vat = parseInt($('.invoice-vat').attr('data-vat-rate')),
            c_ship = parseInt($('.calculate.shipping').val()) || 0,
            withShip = parseInt(subT + c_ship);

        $('.invoice-sub-total').text(subT.toFixed(2));
        $('#invoice_subtotal').val(subT.toFixed(2));
        $('.invoice-discount').text(disc.toFixed(2));
        $('#invoice_discount').val(disc.toFixed(2));

        if($('.invoice-vat').attr('data-enable-vat') === '1') {

            if($('.invoice-vat').attr('data-vat-method') === '1') {
                $('.invoice-vat').text(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_vat').val(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('.invoice-total').text((withShip).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_total').val((withShip).toFixed(2));
            } else {
                $('.invoice-vat').text(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_vat').val(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('.invoice-total').text((withShip + ((vat / 100) * withShip)).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_total').val((withShip + ((vat / 100) * withShip)).toFixed(2));
            }
        } else {
            $('.invoice-total').text((withShip).toFixed(2));
            $('#invoice_total').val((withShip).toFixed(2));
        }

    }

    function actionAddProduct(){

        if($(".required").val() == ''){
            $(".required").parent().addClass("has-error");
            $("#response").removeClass("alert-success");
            $("#response").addClass("alert-warning");
            $("#response .message").html("<strong>Error</strong>: It appear's you have forgotten to complete something!");
            $("#response").fadeIn();
        } else {
            var $btn = $("#action_add_product").button("loading");

            $.ajax({

                url: 'response.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#add_product").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#response .message").html("<strong>" + data.status + "</strong>: " + data.message);
                    $("#response").removeClass("alert-warning");
                    $("#response").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#response").fadeIn();
                    $btn.button("reset");       
                },
                error: function(data){
                    $("#response .message").html("<strong>" + data.status + "</strong>: " + data.message);
                    $("#response").removeClass("alert-success");
                    $("#response").addClass("alert-warning");
                    $("#response").fadeIn();
                    $btn.button("reset");  
                } 

            });
        }

    }

    function actionCreateInvoice(){

        if($(".required").val() == ''){
            $(".required").parent().addClass("has-error");
            $("#response").removeClass("alert-success");
            $("#response").addClass("alert-warning");
            $("#response .message").html("<strong>Error</strong>: It appear's you have forgotten to complete something!");
            $("#response").fadeIn();
        } else {
            var $btn = $("#action_create_invoice").button("loading");

            $.ajax({

                url: 'response.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#create_invoice").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#response .message").html("<strong>" + data.status + "</strong>: " + data.message);
                    $("#response").removeClass("alert-warning");
                    $("#response").addClass("alert-success");
                    $("#response").fadeIn();
                    $btn.button("reset");

                    console.log(data);      
                },
                error: function(data){
                    $("#response .message").html("<strong>" + data.status + "</strong>: " + data.message);
                    $("#response").removeClass("alert-success");
                    $("#response").addClass("alert-warning");
                    $("#response").fadeIn();
                    $btn.button("reset");  
                } 

            });
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Fixed shipping issue, anyone have any idea son 200 undefined issue?